# \parbox inside \colorbox ends up being to wide

Tags: width, colorbox

Can you tell me why the following code always ends up being to wide (minimal example)?

It seems to be independent of the environment so I assume that `\colorbox` has some additional margin? How can I turn that off?

`\colorbox{gray!20}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering some text}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\colorbox` uses the same `\fboxsep` padding as `\fbox` so use `\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}` or set `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}`

Comment: And add `\noindent` or `\centering`…

Comment: @Bernard yes perhaps although OP asked about colorbox and that would apply equally if just parbox was used so I didn't mention that, I assume it's handled