# Width of parbox inside colorbox

Tags: marginpar, parbox, colorbox

I want to insert a colorbox into a margin paragraph. `parbox` is used to keep the line breaks.

What value should I pass to `\parbox`'s width so it doesn't get too wide as it does now?

[image: colorbox]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,calc}
\geometry{%
left=16mm,
textwidth=130mm,
marginparsep=8mm,
marginparwidth=50mm,
showframe}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
\marginpar{%
  \colorbox{orange}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
    }
  }%
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

The expression `\dimexpr\marginparwidth-2\fboxsep` is based [on this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336728/180429) but I don't see its effect.

Comment: you have the right width but you have a space after the parbox inside the colorbox, add `%` after `}` and similarly you have a space after the coilorbox in tehmarginpar so add a second `%`

Comment: both `\fbox{x }` is not the same as `\fbox{x}`

Comment: Got you. That works.

Comment: Would you like to post an answer, or shall I ask the moderator to close the question? If you could write down a sentence about the reason for why it happened, it would be very instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding spaces

```
...uat.}
    }
  }%
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

should be

```
uat.}%
    }%
  }%
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

a line end is a space compare

```
\fbox{\fbox{x}}
```

with

```
\fbox{x
 }
}

\fbox{x%
 }%
}
```